# Effective Communication between Worker and UI Threads

Tags: multithreading

I am designing real-time windows application displaying graphics or images gotten from multiple sensors. I assigned a thread for getting data from each sensor, and a UI thread for each display. According to MSDN, I can employ PostThreadMessage to send a message to another thread.

That sounds fine but in my architecture, a worker thread needs to send lots of information such as image. So I don't think I can send single big image data to UI thread with PostThreadMessage because the worker thread has to hold that data until corresponding UI thread processes it.

If so, what is best way to send the large amount data from worker thread to UI thread?

1. I thought about saving it as a file but I am sure it can be big bottleneck as it requires to process the data very quickly.
2. One idea I have is to send very small part, for example, few lines of image,  when you send a message from worker thread.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to send all the data.  You have it in memory.  You have a pointer to it.  Just send the pointer, and then synchronize access.

Comment: @jeffamaphone Thanks for your input. I understand I can have a pointer and send it with message. From that point, however, the data should be synced and processing would be slow down. I would rather have async process so each thread does not have to wait much. But that's my idea. Please point out if I am wrong.

Comment: @Paul: Leave the freeing of the images memory to the ui-thread, and allocate new memory for the next image in the worker thread. So the worker thread does not have to wait until the ui-thread is finished with the image. Requires more memory, but no copying or long waits will be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my comment as an answer:
As jeffamaphone wrote, use the pointer to the memory instead of copying everything. Thats the advantage of threads - shared memory - dont waste it.
Leave the freeing of the images memory to the ui-thread, and allocate new memory for the next image in the worker thread. So the worker thread does not have to wait until the ui-thread is finished with the image. Requires more memory, but no copying or long waits will be necessary.

There are possible improvements, which can reduce the number of allocations you will have to make, but they are quite fiddly - and its quite doutable that they indeed would improve performance, because they would reintroduce some kind of synchronisation. So i would go ahead and implement it like i suggested, and if you notice that the amount of memory allocations is a performance bottleneck, you/we can rethink this matter.

Comment: Well, if the images are always the same size, the OP could push the 'used' images onto a producer-consumer queue after they have been displayed on the UI thread.  The sensor-input thread/s could pop images from this queue instead of new/malloc them.  This optimization removes malloc/free and provides flow-control while only adding a brief lock while the image instances/pointers are pushed/popped from the queue. Only helps if the images are always the same size or can be located at some buffer block whose size forms a maximum limit to the size of the image data 'union'.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. For now, I will leave this question open to get more input for a couple of days. After that will accept the answer. Thanks again.